# VueJS Property or method "posts" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js

I have seen many versions of this question but I can't seem to find an answer!
I have this code in `app.js`:

```
Vue.component('blog', require('./components/Blog.vue').default);

var blog = new Vue({
  el: "#blog",
    data() {
      return {
        posts: null
      }
  },
  mounted() {
    Axios.get('api/blogposts')
      .then(response => (this.posts = response.data))
  }
});
```

When I reference `posts` in my template, I get the error:

```
Property or method "posts" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

My code is basically identical to the documentation. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how do you use it exactly?

Comment: Can you please add your `template` markup to this post?

Comment: set posts to undefined instead of null, I assume during the render the axios.get has not finished, and does not set posts to something usable.

Comment: It doesn't really matter HOW I use it in the template. For the sake of just seeing the posts, let's say that my template contains: `{{ posts }}`

Comment: Which template references `posts`? Is it the template in the element `#blog` or the template of `Blog.vue`?

Comment: It is `Blog.vue` where I am getting the error.

Comment: `Blog.vue` will not be able to see that `posts` property. You need a `posts` property inside `Blog.vue` itself. If you want to pass it down from the root Vue instance you can use a prop.

Comment: @skirtle very nice. I did not realize that. Thanks for the help!